# How to Wrap this Mesh around my Shoe Model?

Tags: modeling, objects, shrinkwrap

I wanted to recreate the shoe below but I am having trouble with properly wrapping the details around the base shoe mesh. How do i wrap a mesh around the shoe?

[image: Reference Image]

I want to wrap this detail.

[image: Details]

This is the base mesh of the shoe.

[image: Base Mesh]

Comment: hint: never ask for an opinioned based question because these questions will quickly be closed (read the rules for this site if you want to). Better change to "what is an efficient way..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your detail object is separate you can deform it with modifiers:

- Create a plane, subdivide it a bit, make it a bit larger than your detail, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, don't activate the modifier for the moment:

[image]

- Give a *Surface Deform* modifier to your detail with the plane as *Target*, click on the *Bind* button:

[image]

- Make the *Shrinkwrap* of the plane visible, the detail will deform, move it towards the shoe so that it sticks:

[image]

**Or** use the *Knife Project* tool:

- Create your detail, remove the faces only, choose the front view, select your shoe, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click to select the detail:

[image]

- Go into the *Mesh panel > Knife Project*:

[image]

- It has cut the detail shape on the surface of the shoe:

[image]

- Extrude the selection:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I am definitely gonna try this technique.

Comment: Nice‼️‼️looks like I am still a modifier noob ‍♂️+1

Comment: @Chris you're lost in Geometry Nodes, come back to the basics now  ;)

Comment: You are right! But they are just so damn fascinating! And powerful! like Superman…you know?